# How to understand situations like in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I made up the sentence:

> I left the beans to soak overnight.

Is the verb "soak" connected to "I" or "the beans"? Which subject is supposed to soak? Thank you.

Comment: If you made it up, you should know what you meant!  It's hardly likely that anyone would understand it to mean "I abandoned the beans in order to go and spend the night in the bath".

Comment: Who was wet in the morning? You or the beans?

Comment: Does it mean that I soaked the beans overnight or the beans soaked overnight? In sentence "Let the beans soak overnight" the beans perform soaking.

Comment: We can use normally transitive verbs in this way: I left the beans to soak, cook, freeze, boil, cool, burn. It is understood that the action is performed on the beans, not by them.

Comment: "The beans are soaking" doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: It makes sense, and is normal. Many verbs can be used [transitively or intransitively](https://www.wordsmyth.net/blog/2019/02/%EF%BB%BFgrammar-and-usage-transitive-intransitive-verbs/). Although it’s common practice to speak of “transitive verbs” and “intransitive verbs,” it may be more appropriate to speak of transitive and intransitive senses of individual verbs. `Soak` is marked `I or T` in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soak)

Answer (score 1):

It is the beans that are soaking  You can express this transitively or intransitively:

> I soaked the beans overnight

> The beans soaked overnight

If you use other verbs you see the subject can be ambiguous

> I left Joe to eat the beans and went home.

Here it seems that Joe is probably the subject.

> I left Paris to explore the world.

Here the subject is probably "I".  In both these cases there is a little ambiguity.  Contextual clues have to be used to interpret the meaning. (For example a town can't explore the world.)

Returning to your sentence,  there is formally some ambiguity in the parsing, but contextual clues strongly suggest that it is the beans that are soaking.

But, just for fun:

> I had been shelling bean pods all day, but when my mother called for me to have a long long bath, I left the beans to soak overnight in the bath and get myself as wrinkled as prune by morning!

Comment: Might that be better described as "transitively or ergatively"?

Answer (score 0):

Of course **soak** is connected to **the beans**. To know this you only need to make a question: "Who is soaking? I or the beans?". You may use this with all verbs.

Comment: "I left her to finish the job". Does it mean I left her in order to finish the job or I left her so that she finishes the job?

Comment: good example, both your options are possible. The beans example is different, because of logic. Do you know any person who would leave beans and then go soak themselves?  That is weird. Your "finish the job" examples are completely logical.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Is the sentence "the beans are soaking" correct? Does it make sense?