# How to use "soak"?

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

Which is incorrect?

1. I soaked the beans overnight.
2. The beans was soaked overnight.
3. The beans soaked overnight.

Comment: Hello Vova,  has it been six months, and your beans are still soaking? (Related question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252259/how-to-understand-situations-like-in-the-following-sentence  )

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about that, my question was answered long ago.

Answer (score 2):

The only incorrect one is number 2: it should be "The beans **were** soaked overnight". Apart from that, they're all fine. This is because "beans" is **plural**, and so follows the conjugation for "we"/"they". If the subject were "bean", the sentence would be "the bean **was** soaking overnight".

Comment: I think that this answer may be improved by explaining why this is the case - for instance,  by mentioning that "the bean was soaking overnight" is correct,  and explaining the difference between them.

Comment: There is no need in doing that. The mistake took place only because I forgot that the subject was plural.